# Magento - Add to Cart

Tags: magento, cart

I´m using this Code (in cartsontroller.php) to add a extra Product to Cart Page - but I dont see it in Cart itself?

There are no Errors  or something like that...

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(25); 
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save(); 
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: Tested your code and it works. What is "cartsontroller.php" this isn't a normal Magento name for a controller, are you sure it's called? Maybe you have a typo "CartController.php"?

Comment: well i just typed it wrong - i put that code in cartcontroller.php (not cartsontroller.php) -  do you see that item in cart?

Comment: Okay now i´m bit deeper into it....

When I´m adding a product to cart - i see the product as it should be and i see the message that my "extra" product was added too. But its not in Cart , do i have to add a new quote item or something like that to show it ?

Comment: UPDATE: Okay my mistake was that i wasn´t it adding into Function "public function addAction()" on cartcontroller.php - how stupid =D